# Windows live hotmail on iPhone

Tags: iphone

Setting up mail on my iPhone, I didn't see an option for MS Live Mail/Hotmail.  I understand (due my mastery of search engines) that there are a few options. What's the best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came back to add an update:

In iOS 5 or later, you can add Microsoft Hotmail natively on the "add account" setup screen.

(In May, 2012, I started getting errors in my iPhone Exchange account setup, so I had to delete the account and re-connect via the iOS Hotmail account setup).

See http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1694 for setup instructions.

Answer (score 4):

The priority for accessing any email service would be:

1. **Exchange**: Push email, folders, syncs read/unread status, contact sync, calendar sync
2. **IMAP**: Folders, syncs read/unread status
3. **POP3**: Bare bones email reading, usually only useful for a single client unless you "keep a copy on the server"

It seems that some people have had success using [Exchange](http://www.iphonedownloadblog.com/2010/06/17/how-to-set-up-hotmail-for-ms-exchange-on-your-iphone/); IMAP seems to require either a premium account or 3rd party software; and [POP3 is possible](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1694) for free accounts.

Keep an eye on [Apple's page](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1694) as they will probably update it as new solutions are added by Microsoft.

Comment: Microsoft has now "Exchange-enabled" all hotmail accounts. http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2010/08/windows-live-hotmail-gets-exchange-activesync.ars

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, Microsoft doesn't allow Hotmail IMAP access. The workaround is [IzyMail](http://v3.izymail.com/default.aspx). I haven't tried it, but it seems like it works as an intermediary between the iPhone and Hotmail servers in order to get a "simulated" IMAP experience lol.

Senseful's post has a good information. I use Exchange for my work email, calendars and contacts, and I love it. Gmail works really well with IMAP, and I really do not like POP3 from past experiences.

Comment: You should also note that izymail doesn't appear to be a free service.